# Footer bar not displayed as a footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I'm trying to add from the starter template bootstrap4, the sticky footer at the bottom of the html page.
Unfortunately, the footer still in the middle of the page instead of be as a footer.

I don't understand why
Both css files (starter-template.css, sticky-footer.css) from the template are located at the same level of the index.html

[image: screen from the index.html]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.1.1">
  <title>Boostrap NavBar & Footer</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/starter-template/">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .bd-placeholder-img {
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">NavBar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item disabled">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Two</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Three</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>Sticky footer</h1><br>
      <p class="lead">Pin a footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>

    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the html and the body to have 100% height:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">NavBar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
      aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item disabled">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Two</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Three</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>Sticky footer</h1><br>
      <p class="lead">Pin a footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>

    </div>

  </main><!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: sticky;` with `bottom:0`

```css
body{
margin:0;}
footer {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
  <meta name="generator" content="Jekyll v4.1.1">
  <title>Boostrap NavBar & Footer</title>

  <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/starter-template/">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .bd-placeholder-img {
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      text-anchor: middle;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
        font-size: 3.5rem;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="sticky-footer.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">NavBar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item disabled">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Two</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Three</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>Sticky footer</h1><br>
      <p class="lead">Pin a footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>

    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="../assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```